# Weird color under /dev/ using iterm2 Solarized Dark theme

Tags: iterm2

[image]

I'm using iterm2 with color presets "Solarized dark" + oh-my-zsh. The color looks really weird under /dev/ folder when I type "ls" command.
Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

This is not particular to solarized theme or iterm, indeed. This is also true for the vanilla theme and also for macos terminal.

As I learned [here](https://linuxconfig.org/identifying-file-types-in-linux), linux (and also macos) stores metadata for file types, and all of the painted ones are of type "character device". You can assert that by doing `ls -l` and checking their linux rwx string starts with the letter "c". Quoting the referenced webpage:

> Character and block device files allow users and programs to
> communicate with hardware peripheral devices.

So this is the standard way terminals in macos choose to display elements of the filesystem hierarchy that are neither files not directories nor simlinks.